# Does exist an Elliptic analogue of Benaloh encryption scheme?

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, homomorphic-encryption, quadratic-residuosity

The definition of Benaloh encryption scheme can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benaloh_cryptosystem).

```
Does exist an elliptic analogue of this scheme?
```

I want to use this scheme but the length of the key is very big(like $2048$). If you can do something similar for elliptic curves it would be great.

Comment: It doesn't look immediately likely that there's an EC analogue.  Benaloh's scheme depends on (among other things) that the order of the group being secret; with an EC group, it is public; hence the "residuosity problem" would be easy for anyone. BTW: what are the properties of the Benaloh scheme that makes it attractive?  Is it some homomorphic property?

Comment: I see it doesnt work in an obvious way. But I know that there is similarity between discrete logarithm and RSA problem. Can we generalise Benaloh to make it work for any hidden subgroup problem?

Comment: 2 property. 1)It is additively homomorphic 2)The size of massage space can be much less than the size of the group, so encryption can be made more effective than, say, in ElGamal